# Дурацкий вопрос: можно ли перенаправлять трафик через вк?

Tags: прокси, трафик

Есть ли способ перенаправлять трафик через вк, фейсбук, одноклассники или ватсап? Знаю, что вк недавно запустил прокси для Украины, но в нем для меня нет толка, т.к. я не знаю айпи и порта

Comment: Вы хотите, что бы они Вам предоставляли прокси?

Comment: Ну, что-то типа того

Comment: Если Вы их ломанете, то да, конечно предоставят доступ. Но ненадолго. А прокси для Украины ВК не запускал, за ненадобностью

Comment: Запускал же недавно. Ну ладно и на том спасибо https://tjournal.ru/45412-vkontakte-dobavila-proksi-server-v-obnovlennoe-prilozhenie-dlya-android

Comment: не читайте фейковых новостей.